# PHP Post with Square Brackets

Tags: php, post

I understand how to handle $_POST[] variables if there are no square brackets in the form id.

```
<input id="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>" />
$id="phone";
<input id="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST[$id]; ?>" />
```

I want to do the same as above, but I want to use a form id with square brackets.  Is this possible?

```
<input id="phone[mobile]" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']['mobile']; ?>" />
$id="phone['mobile']";
<input id="phone[mobile]" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Do you understand what the *square brackets* are?

Comment: This is a job for the `name` attribute *NOT* the `id`.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Post a form?  Get the form's values?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: me thinks you **don't** understand brackets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `name` attribute, however you can use brackets (or arrays) in input fields:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCB[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCB[]" value="2" />
```

...

```
$myCB = $_POST['myCB'];

foreach ($myCB as $key => $value) {
    echo $key ." - ". $value ."<br />";
}
```